# Convert var value to Datatble C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have queried my datatable using Linq to SQL and have to convert var value to  datatable again. Can anybody help me?

```
var results = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where myRow.Field<string>("Name") == "HP"
                          select myRow;
```

Datatable datatable=results?????

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please be way more specific. What do you hope to happen? What's happening? What have you tried to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to copy `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to `DataTable`.

```
DataTable table = results.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I answered 11 seconds after you so I will delete my answer.